# Union all dataframes stored in a nested dictionary - Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dictionary that essentially looks like:

```
dct = {'a':{'df':dfa, 'group':1, 'att':col1},
       'b': {'df':dfb, 'group':2, 'att':col2},
       'c': {'df':dfc, 'group':3, 'att':col3},
      }
```

My dictionary is much longer which is why I'm looking to union all the of the dataframes in a more efficient way than I'm currently doing:

```
df = dct['a']['df'].union(dct['b']['df']).union(dct['c']['df'])....etc.
```

Comment: let us know your expected output?, your spark version

Comment: running on spark > 3.1. Expected output would be equivalent to pandas.concat([dfa, dfb, dfc), axis=0])

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

output = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, [dct[key]['df'] for key in dct.keys()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `union()` or also [unionByName()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName.html) which has the advantage of combining dataframes with different columns if you specify `allowMissingColumns=True`. You may also want a `distinct()` at the end if you don't want to retain duplicates among the dataframes in the dictionary:

```py
df = dct['a']['df']
for k in list(dct.keys())[1:]:
    df = df.unionByName(dct[k]['df'], allowMissingColumns=True)
df = df.distinct()
```